# Schema.org type for telecom services pages

Tags: schema.org

We are dealing with a large website that offers a number of telecom, cable & satellite services nationwide. For the last two types of services I have found [`CableOrSatelliteService`](http://schema.org/CableOrSatelliteService).

But I am a bit puzzled what to chose for the voice/mobile subscriptions. Would [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) markup be enough?

We have a lot of types of subscriptions (each subscription type has multiple prices, depending on the resources included), each with its own page.

Comment: Why do you want to use a schema?   Many people do so because they are under the mistaken impression that it will help search engine rankings.   It won't.   At most Google changes how a listing looks in the search results based on schema.  However Google only uses a small number of schema to do so, and they list the ones they use here:  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery    If you can't figure which schema you should be using, that is usually a pretty good indication that you shouldn't be using one.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thank you for your reply.
We don't want to use it only for the way our pages might look in search results, although that's definetly a bonus. And increasing our CTR in SERPs is a good aim, even if it's not guaranteed to be used. It's also a good method to structure data in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) type has these subtypes:

- `BroadcastService`
- `CableOrSatelliteService`
- `FinancialProduct`
- `FoodService`
- `GovernmentService`
- `TaxiService`
- `WebAPI`

As there isn’t a subtype specifically for voice/mobile services, you should go with the closest parent that is suitable, which is `Service`.

So, all your services (cable, satellite, voice, mobile) would be of type `Service`, and the first two would be of type `CableOrSatelliteService` in addition. You don’t have to specify both types for them: by using a subtype, all parent types automatically apply, too.